# php Get value from SimpleXMLElement Object

Tags: php

I have this code:

```
    echo "<pre>Disk Limit: ";
    print_r($result['disklimit']);
    echo "</pre>";
```

which outputs:

```
    Disk Limit: SimpleXMLElement Object
    (
        [0] => 990000M
    )
```

In simple words, this is what I want to show:

```
    Disk Limit: 990000M
```

I have searched similar questions but couldn't find an appropriate answer.
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Great! Worked like a charm... Thanks a lot

Comment: I was so confused...I had used this code b=in my script before but forgot.. :P Thanks nyways :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess this should just work:

```
echo "Disk Limit: ".$result['disklimit'][0];
```

or did I miss something?